# Confused about RLC series circuit waveform reading: Please help

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, oscilloscope, multisim

[image]

Hi everyone,

I simulated this simple circuit, but I am a little confused about my voltage readings. I calculated VL1 to be 1.279Vrms or 1.81V-pk, however, on the oscilloscope I'm getting a much different voltage reading (around 5.7Vpk). Any help regarding this? Not sure what I am doing wrong.

(White = source, and red = Vl1)

Thanks.

---

Edited information following answer: -

[image]

Comment: Your calculation of 1.279 V rms is correct.

Comment: Why are the node lines black on the left side of the inductor and red on the right side of the inductor? Maybe there is an error in the wiring tool?

Comment: I will remake it and change that to see whether that is the issue, thanks

Comment: Is the `PrintScreen` not working?

Comment: May I ask which software you are using in these screenshots? Seems well made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get near-enough the same as your number using my [crappy website calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20HPF/RCL%20HPF.html): -

[image]

So, at close to 10 kHz the transfer function is -6.81 dB. With an input of 2.828 volts RMS, that's an output of 0.45656 x 2.828 volts = 1.291 volts RMS.

Maybe, you are not inverting the channels correctly on the virtual scope. You should be using the virtual scope differentially with one channel inverted to get the right answer: -

[image]

At the moment you are adding the voltage on one side of the inductor to the voltage on the other side - subtraction is needed.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm not sure what you mean about inverting one channel of the scope? What does this do and why? thanks

Comment: @Younesel-kaisi see the edit in my answer.

Comment: do you mean connect channel B negative across the inductor and the positive to the ground? Or do you mean Track the inductor with Channel A and source with B? Thanks

Comment: The two wires going to input B need swapping over @Younesel-kaisi - B+ connects to A- etc.. And you need to measure A and B differentially - you need to set up the scope channels for that. Or, re-wire your circuit like mine above where the inductor is swapping places with the resistor. I suspect that the ground node is at the lower end of the resistor; yes? I can't tell where the ground is on your circuit because your picture doesn't indicate that.

Comment: I don't know how these virtual scopes work but, maybe the scope input can be wired directly across the input i.e. B+ to one side of the inductor and B- to the other side of the inductor.

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out, I got the result I wanted but I don't understand why I got it. i'll update my post with the new picture

Comment: Just show the connections to the scope like I did.

Comment: Check my edited post the top wave is the source and the bottom is VL1. This is what it should look like I believe.

Comment: OK that exactly replicates what I said in my previous but one comment: `maybe the scope input can be wired directly across the input i.e. B+ to one side of the inductor and B- to the other side of the inductor.`

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't amend your question like this. Once an answer is given you have to respect those answers so... place the new picture in a special "edit" section below the main body of the original question and, well-done. [Please take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to know how to accept the answer and close down this session.

Comment: Yes you are correct you could connect it across. This just confused me and didn't make much sense because in real life you always connect to the same ground point. I really appreciate your help though and yeah I will make a special edit section. Thank you dearly sir!

Comment: @Younesel-kaisi I have properly edited your answer to differentiate the original question from the added section. Please take the two minute tour to find out how to accept my answer.